# Can't get thumbnail from AVAsset

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, avasset

In my Xamarin.Forms project, I use dependency injection to call a method inside my .iOS project in order to retrieve a thumbnail of a video that the user just recorded.

Called from my Xamarin.Forms project:

```
byte[] thumbnailBytes = DependencyService.Get<IMediaMetaData>().ReturnVidThumbnailBytes(vid.Path);
```

The following code is then called from the .IOS project:

```
public class MediaMetaData : IMediaMetaData
{
    public byte[] ReturnVidThumbnailBytes(string videoFilePath)
    {
        // videoFilePath example = 
        // /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3E84C0D0-F590-4AAF-89E7-7D3BFC023E6B/Documents/temp/trim_160491789522565DC08BE-862C-4EE0-A135-BCD9236C6874.mov

        //Take local url and create an AVAsset
        AVAsset asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(new NSUrl(videoFilePath));

        AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator.FromAsset(asset);

        // Total duration of asset
        CMTime actualTime = asset.Duration;

        // 1/60 = 60th of a second
        CMTime cmTime = new CMTime(1, 10);

        NSError error;
        var imageRef = assetImageGenerator.CopyCGImageAtTime(cmTime, out actualTime, out error);

        if (imageRef == null)
            return null;

        var image = UIImage.FromImage(imageRef);
        return image.AsJPEG().ToArray();
    }
}
```

The problem:

CopyCGImageAtTime always returns null. I check the NSError and I get the following information:

Class Handle = Unable to cast object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue

code = -11850

Localized failure reason = The server is not correctly configured (But wait, this is a local file I'm accessing here...?)

I've not been able to find any helpful information regarding the class handle error, and the localized failure reason brings up threads from people who are trying to access videos from web services as opposed to local storage. Anyone have experience with the problem I'm having?

Comment: Try to  add the line  `assetImageGenerator.AppliesPreferredTrackTransform = true;`

Comment: I had that line already but removed it since it didn't seem necessary, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: If it still doesn't work , you could share your sample to github and I will check it .

Comment: I don't actually have a github account yet hahaha, I'm slightly busy with some other bugs right now but I will try to remembe to do that, much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, why do you need it on github? It's a work project, I'm not in a position to upload all of the project code

Comment: You could create a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Ahh okay I see what ya mean :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224321/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-david-andrew-thorpe).